# Primefaces dataTable with select and dragable rows, select fails when rows are reordered

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces dataTable which is both select-able (single selection) and has draggable rows. I also need to select a row via a button (apart from being able to select the row itself). My view code is:

```
<p:dataTable id="itemTable" widgetVar="itemTable"
   var="item" draggableRows="true"
   value="#{routesModelBean.itemList}" selectionMode="single"
   selection="#{routesModelBean.selectedItem}"
   rowKey="#{item.id}" rowIndexVar="rowId">

<p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
        onclick="PF('itemTable').unselectAllRows();PF('itemTable').selectRow(#{rowId},false);" type="button">
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

The problem seems to be the "rowIndexVar". For example, if i have two items in my list and i swap them by dragging, then clicking the button of one item will result in selecting the other.

Edit: Primefaces version is 6.0

Comment: if you use update the table when reordering, like `<p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="YOUR_LISTENER" update=":itemTable" />` does it work?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I stopped using the datatable with both selectable and draggable rows because more problems emerged. Indeed updating the table updates the indexes,

Comment: OK, since it fixes the problem, even though you dont use it anymore, let mel post it as an answer to accept it so as the question to be considered "cleared". thank you.

Comment: Please post version info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reordering the rows you should update the table too. Use the following

```
<p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="YOUR_LISTENER" update=":itemTable" />
```